# Erro- Laravel php artisan

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com este erro na hora de executar o comando `php artisan serve`

```
RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43:
The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

in Encrypter.php line 43
at Encrypter->__construct('', 'AES-256-CBC') in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 27
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 746
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 644
at Container->make('encrypter', array()) in Application.php line 709
at Application->make('encrypter') in Container.php line 864
at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 819
at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 789
at Container->build('App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Container.php line 644
at Container->make('App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Application.php line 709
at Application->make('App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 127
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs\pmo\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Já fiz executei o comando `php artisan key:generate`  no arquivo app.php copiei a chave gerada e coloquei em:

```
'key' => env('[base64:cDFjVAeEyMpey1sGdTBKKDAyY4ipZmOPVBeBpAsqQo4='),//

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Na parte cipher tbm troquei colocando 128 e nada .... gostaria de alguma dica sobre este problema.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9080

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693312/the-only-supported-ciphers-are-aes-128-cbc-and-aes-256-cbc-with-the-correct-key

Comment: Tem algo errado aê, fera. Você colocou `[base64`, não tem esse `[` antes...

Comment: bem observado! @WallaceMaxters enfim... não puder fazer esse teste ,pra ver se modificaria algo,fica apenas a observação.Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pra fechar a pergunta,apenas peguei um backup que tinha, e fiz o procedimento que sempre faço e enfim voltou ao normal.

E olhei no arquivo `app.php` e no trecho onde tinha problemas... está assim
  `key' => env('APP_KEY'),`
   `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',`

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema ao subir um projeto Laravel do Github.
Eu tinha o mesmo erro de: RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43:

Rodando o php artisan key:generate funcionou perfeitamente.